# mockito : 'spy' annotated method ran once declared

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I am trying to create the skeletton of a future app, using : java 8,windows 10, intelliJ, junit5, mockito.
I get a problem while running a test using mockito, it's the first test I write using spies, and it doesn't work.

It seems that the statement `when(client_spy.try_to_connect(anyString(),anyInt())).thenReturn(null);` leads to the execution of the method, which is not expected : I only want to tell to mockito to return null is the method `try_to_connect` is called.
Thus, the method is called in the test, and without parameters, so I get an error in this method.

here is the test class (some parts):

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class unitTestsTry2 {

    private static final String LOCAL_IP = "localhost";
    private static final String REMOTE_IP = "localhost";
    private static final String LOCAL_PORT = "1001";
    private static final String REMOTE_PORT = "1002";
    private static  ApplicationRunner apr=new ApplicationRunner();

    @Spy
    ClientExtremity client_spy=new ClientExtremity();

(...)
    @Test
    void startupAndTryToConnect() {
        apr.client_endpoint = client_spy;
        when(client_spy.try_to_connect(anyString(),anyInt()))
                .thenReturn(null);  <--- THE FAULTLY LINE

        apr.main(new String[]{LOCAL_IP,LOCAL_PORT,REMOTE_IP,REMOTE_PORT});

        verify(((ClientOrders)apr.client_endpoint)).try_to_connect(REMOTE_IP,Integer.parseInt(REMOTE_PORT));

    }
}
```

here is my gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'de.dynamicfiles.projects.gradle.plugins', name: 'javafx-gradle-plugin', version: '8.8.2'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'lorry'
version '1'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/mockito/maven" }
}

apply plugin: 'javafx-gradle-plugin'

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()

}

compileJava.dependsOn clean

jfx {
    // minimal requirement for jfxJar-task
    mainClass = 'lorry.ApplicationRunner'

    // minimal requirement for jfxNative-task
    vendor = 'YourName'

    launcherArguments = ["localhost", "1001", "localhost", "1002"]

    // gradle jfxRun
    runJavaParameter = null // String
    //runAppParameter = "localhost" "1001" "localhost" "1002" // String

    jfxMainAppJarName = "chat.jar"
}

dependencies {

    //testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'javax.websocket', name: 'javax.websocket-api', version: '1.1'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
    //testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.2.0')
    //testRuntimeOnly('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.2.0')


    def final junitVersion = "5.2.0"
    compile group: 'com.google.inject', name: 'guice', version: '4.1.0'
    //compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.2'
    compile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-api', version: junitVersion
    compile group: 'org.assertj', name: 'assertj-core', version: '3.9.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.7'

    testCompile group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-params', version: junitVersion
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.21.0'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:2.21.0'
    testCompile group:'org.junit.jupiter',name:'junit-jupiter-api',version:  junitVersion
    testRuntime group: 'org.junit.jupiter', name: 'junit-jupiter-engine', version: junitVersion

    compile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'

    testCompile "org.testfx:testfx-core:4.0.13-alpha"
    testCompile 'org.testfx:testfx-junit5:4.0.13-alpha'

    compile group: 'org.glassfish.tyrus', name: 'tyrus-server', version: '1.13.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.tyrus/tyrus-client
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.tyrus', name: 'tyrus-client', version: '1.13.1'


}


jar {
    baseName = 'Chat'
    version = ''
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Class-Path': configurations.compile.collect { it.getName() }.join(' '),
                'Main-Class': 'lorry.Chat'
        )
    }
}
```

EDIT
thank you for your answers. I changed my code:

```
@Spy
public ClientExtremity client_spy=new ClientExtremity();

@Test
void startupAndTryToConnect() {
    apr.client_endpoint = client_spy;
    when(client_spy).try_to_connect(anyString(),anyInt()).thenReturn(null);

    apr.main(new String[]{LOCAL_IP,LOCAL_PORT,REMOTE_IP,REMOTE_PORT});

    verify(((ClientOrders)apr.client_endpoint)).try_to_connect(REMOTE_IP,Integer.parseInt(REMOTE_PORT));

}
```

but intelliJ tells to me : Error:(73, 25) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method try_to_connect(java.lang.String,int)
  location: interface org.mockito.stubbing.OngoingStubbing

having the following clientExtremity:

```
@ClientEndpoint(encoders = MessageEncoder.class, decoders = MessageDecoder.class)
public class ClientExtremity implements ClientOrders {



        @OnMessage
        public void onMessage(Message message) {

        }

    @Override
    public Session try_to_connect(String remote_ip, Integer remote_port) {
        ClientManager client = ClientManager.createClient();
        Session session;
        try {
            session = client.connectToServer(ClientExtremity.class, new URI(
                    format("wss://%1$2s:%2$2d/chat",remote_ip,remote_port)
            ));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            session=null;
        }
        return session;
    }
}
```

I can't figure out why the declaration of try_to_connect in the test method fails.

EDIT 2
here is applicationRunner:

```
public class ApplicationRunner {

    public static String localIP, remoteIP;
    public static int localPort, remotePort;
    public static Fenetre fenetre = new Fenetre();
    public static Session session=null;
    public static ClientExtremity client_endpoint=new ClientExtremity();

    public static void init(String[] args) {
        localIP = args[0];
        localPort = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        remoteIP = args[2];
        remotePort = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

        try {
            new Thread(fenetre).start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        session = ((ClientOrders) client_endpoint).try_to_connect(localIP,localPort);



    }

    public static void main (String[]args){
        init(args);

    }
}
```

Comment: I strongly advise you to read `Mockito.spy()`'s javadoc, it explains in length that using when() with spies is dangerous and may lead to that kind of behavior.
On the note of improving your post, rather that showing your build.gradle, you should add your `ApplicationRunner`.

Answer (score 0):

ok, done.
a correct code is:

```
@Test
    void startupAndTryToConnect() {
        ClientExtremity client_spy = spy(new ClientExtremity());
        apr.client_endpoint = client_spy;
        doReturn(null).when(client_spy).try_to_connect(anyString(), anyInt());

        apr.init(new String[]{LOCAL_IP,LOCAL_PORT,REMOTE_IP,REMOTE_PORT});

        verify(client_spy).try_to_connect(REMOTE_IP,Integer.parseInt(REMOTE_PORT));

    }
```

I needed to:

- change @spy by the method 'spy'
- use doReturn/etc... instead of when/etc...
- in doReturn and verify, the only argument is the instance of the class, you have to write e.g. `verify(someObjectInstance,optionalAdditionalParameters).someMethod(someArgsWithMatchers)`
- and because I do no more use `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`, I had to put `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(unitTestsTry2.class);` in a @BeforeAll annotated method.